# jqGrid Search with dynamic date formats based on user locale

Tags: date, search, jqgrid

Im using jqgrid for the first time and everything has worked like a charm till now. Thanks to the developer community.

I have to enable search for the grid and I did, search works for the data type except for date. I have tried hours and  my code in a mess but no luck with this one. Kindly help me with your input and let me know what is it that Im missing.

The input to the grid is an array of objects from salesforce through which I construct the colmodel. The grids date display format is in sync(dynamic) with the salesforce user locale. The column model for Production_Start_Date__clooks like this for a particular user.

```
{name:'Production_Start_Date__c',
editable:false, 
index:'Production_Start_Date__c',
align:'center', width:'121',classes:'dtCls',
sorttype: 'int',
formatter:'date',
searchoptions: {sopt: ['eq'], 
               dataInit : function (elem){
                  j$(elem).datepicker({ changeYear: true,changeMonth: true, showButtonPanel: true});   }},
formatter: function (cellval, opts) {
if(cellval == undefined){return "";}
else{ var date1= new Date(parseInt(cellval)).toLocaleDateString("en-IN"); 
return (new Date(parseInt(cellval))).toLocaleDateString("en-IN");}}},
```

I did try a quiet a few format options with srcformat and newformat but with no breakthrough. Can someone please help me resolve this.

One significant observation  is I see that the search dialog searches for formats like “1436140800000” but not the one that are displayed in the grid like “03/16/2015”. I wish I could attach screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem before and solved it **at the server side**. I think the best solution is to prepare data completely and pass it to jqGrid. So jqGrid does not need to do process in your data. Also, detecting the user's locale is more easy on the server. So, **It's better to do any conversion, before passing data to jqGrid.**

Comment: Thanks for the response. If its the "formatter" part of the code you are referring to which does format related processing, I had no other go, I do have the date in the user locale format on the server side but If I send it to jqgrid as is, IT renders it in milliseconds format (1436140800000). Hnece the conversion is applied in the formatter section to render it in the right format.   Also please note that my ColModel is build entirely in the server side(Salesforce Apex) based on certain configurations. VisualForce and javascript are used to on the client side to render on the page.

Comment: You are welcome! I think the better way is to convert milliseconds format to readable format on the server side. In my project, I have generated colModel, colNames and other option on the server side, same as you. I think the better way is to implement completely **master-slave** structure. This means, server side is master and jqGrid is slave. And if you want to use formatter for doing that, you need to determine user's locale on the client side and this is not a good solution. I think the formatter is good for easy work, for example mapping numbers to value.